# how to read data from json and set it to kendoUI list view

Tags: php, json, kendo-ui

i am try to set data in to kendoUI
this is working demo of what i want to do.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html
and this is what i do:-

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost/dom",
                dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read:  {
                            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/data_get.php",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
```

i have this type of json data in my `data_get.php` file

```
[{"ProductID":"1","ProductName":"jkl","UnitPrice":"50","UnitsInStock":"50","Discontinued":"1"}]
```

i am try to set this data in to kendoUI list view.
but not able to do this.
i dont know what i do wrong.
Please Help to Out With this.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the given json data is what you get from your PHP script, you have to change your datatype to "json". Jsonp is json data with a wrapped function, which does no apply in your case.